# How to get rid of styling when using Link Component in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html-table, react-router

I have a table in my application, in which when the user clicks a row of that table, then they are redirected to another page of the application. When I'm applying the link component to each row of the table, then the styling of the row gets messed up.

**So here's how it should be actually looking ( it actually looks like this when I don't apply the link component to each row of the table ):**

[image: How the table should be actually looking]

**And here's how it looks when I apply the link component to each row of the table:**

[image: How the table looks when I apply the link component to each row]

**Below is the code that I have for rendering the table:**

```
  /*
  * Method for rendering the table
  * @param {Array} TableData - Table containing the list of products
  */
  renderTable = TableData => {
    return TableData.map((item, i) => (
      <tr key={i}>
        <Link to="/productServices/:productID">
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>{item.productName}</td>
        <td>{item.description}</td>
        <td>{item.department}</td>
        </Link>
      </tr>
    ));
  };
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're inputting an invalid HTML inside your `tr` tag and it breaks the whole layout.

You're only supposed to use `td` and `th` to control size and flow of your Table row (`tr`). You could use `onClick` handler on the Table row but **it wouldn't be nice for accessibility and you would be imperatively controlling navigation on your application**.

Here is how it would look with `onClick`:

```js
  const handleNavigation = () => {
    // run react-router code for imperative navigation  
  }

  /*
  * Method for rendering the table
  * @param {Array} TableData - Table containing the list of products
  */
  renderTable = TableData => {
    return TableData.map((item, i) => (
      <tr key={i} onClick={handleNavigation}> 
        <td>1.</Link></td>
        <td>{item.productName}</td>
        <td>{item.description}</td>
        <td>{item.department}</td>
      </tr>
    ));
  };
```

My proposal is to pass a `Link` inside each `td. It wouldn't break the styling but also would give the ability for the user to click on any place of your Table row and navigate appropriate:

```js
  /*
  * Method for rendering the table
  * @param {Array} TableData - Table containing the list of products
  */
  renderTable = TableData => {
    return TableData.map((item, i) => (
      <tr key={i}> 
        <td><Link to="/productServices/:productID">1.</Link></td>
        <td><Link to="/productServices/:productID">{item.productName}</Link></td>
        <td><Link to="/productServices/:productID">{item.description}</Link></td>
        <td><Link to="/productServices/:productID">{item.department}</Link></td>
      </tr>
    ));
  };
```

[Here is a very simple example of the code above, on a simplified table. With the styling to make the link 100%.](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-grothendieck-8c99c)

You can further extend this to be a component that you'll use to wrap contents of a Table cell inside a link and reuse across your tables.

Comment: First of all thanks for the explanation, I applied this trick and it's working but the trade-off with this trick is that the user is redirected only when he/she click on the textual info given in a row (just like a hyperlink) and what I want is that the user should be redirected by just clicking on the row itself. Any ideas as to how I can achieve that functionality. Thanks!

Comment: @AnmolSarraf I added an example link of a simple implementation of a `<Link>` inside `td` with styling. You can see that with a small CSS change the Link takes the whole cell and the row is clickable.

Comment: Thank you so much @Inacio Schweller. The example you gave perfectly matches my need. :-)